# C system calls — keep getting error with lseek and read

Tags: c, unix, system

This is a practice exercise I am working on for class and I don't understand why this won't run...

I get the problem when trying to assign a char array (buffer) with a length from a variable (num2).

You can execute the file like so:

```
./file.c offset numOfChars filename.txt

./file.c 4 10 somefile.txt
```

If somefile contained the text:

> Why isn't this c program working.  I can't figure it out

The program should print

> isn't this

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

main(int ac, char *av[]){
    // Save the command line variables
    int num1 = av[1];
    int num2 = av[2];

    long numbyte1 = av[1];
    long numbyte2 = av[2];

    int fd = open(av[3], O_RDONLY);

    // Try to open the file
    if( fd < 0 )
        perror(fd + " - Could not open file!");

    // use stat to get file size
    struct stat sb;
    if(fstat(fd,&sb) < 0)    
        return 1;

    // Check to see if the file is big enough for the provided offset
    if(sb.st_size < num1+num2){
        perror(fd + " - Size of file is not large enough for provided offset!" + fd);
    }

    char buffer[num2];

    if(lseek(fd, numbyte1 ,SEEK_SET) < 0) return 1;

    if(read(fd, buffer, numbyte2) != numbyte2) return 1;

    printf("%s\n", buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: (1) Pay attention to your compilers warnings. (2) Make sure your compiler gives you warnings (you're probably using `gcc`, so `-Wall` is the bare minimum; I use `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -std=c11`). (3) If you run into problems, print the data — for the `lseek()`, print the offset you're seeking too. I know you think you know the value, but you don't know the value, and printing the value would show you that you have completely the wrong offset. In case of doubt, have the program tell you what it is doing. This is a critical but basic debugging technique.

Answer (score 1):

Issues that I see:

1. `./file.c` is not the proper way to run the program. You need to compile the program and create an executable. Then, you can run it.

   If you have `gcc`, use:

   ```
   gcc -o file -Wall file.c
   ./file 4 10 somefile.txt
   ```
2. These lines

   ```
   int num1 = av[1];
   int num2 = av[2];
   ```

   are not right. The compiler should report warnings. Using `gcc`, I get the following warnings for those two lines:

   ```
   soc.c: In function ‘main’:
   soc.c:4:15: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
   int num1 = av[1];
              ^
   soc.c:5:15: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
   int num2 = av[2];
   ```

   `av[1]` and `av[2]` are of type `char*`. If the contain integers, you can extract the integers from them by using one of several functions from the standard library. E.g.

   ```
   int num1 = atoi(av[1]);
   int num2 = atoi(av[2]);
   ```
3. The lines

   ```
   long numbyte1 = av[1];
   long numbyte2 = av[2];
   ```

   suffer from the same problem. You can use the already extracted numbers to intiaize `numbypte1` and `numbypte2`

   ```
   long numbyte1 = num1;
   long numbyte2 = num2;
   ```
4. You have

   ```
   char buffer[num2];
   ```

   that will be not enough to hold a string that has `num2` characters. You need another element in the array to hold the terminating null character. Use:

   ```
   char buffer[num2+1];
   ```
5. Add a terminating null character to `buffer` after you read the data from the file.

   ```
   if(read(fd, buffer, numbyte2) != numbyte2) return 1;
   buffer[num2] = '\0';
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I know that, I figured it was given.  There is a problem with the code.

Comment: @KevinZaki: Don't do things like "I figured it was given [that you know you compile the code in `file.c` into a program]".  Around here, nothing can be assumed; beginners make the most peculiar mistakes, and we have to take people at their word.  Be explicit and accurate and don't expose yourself as careless.  (Note that `file` is usually a program on the system; it is best not to call your own program by that name, and `test` is another name that should not be used.  OTOH, `program` is not preempted — but `command` is.)

Comment: Bravo @Jonathan Leffler! Well said, and true.